# Why is Adaptive Gaussian-Hermite quadrature better than Laplace estimation for binomial distributions?

Tags: r, estimation, binomial-distribution

I've read that Adaptive Gaussian-Hermite quadrature is better for binomial distributions than Laplace estimation is, but would like to understand how it works/why it’s better.

**My particular situation**: I have a mixed model with a two-way interaction and random intercepts for participant. When I tried it with Laplace, the interaction was significant, but wasn't trustworthy due to the `model nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio` message. I've just tried it with G-H quadrature (`nAGQ = 0`) and the message went away.

Is this certainly a respected way to address this problem? And if so, will I need to justify the change, and should I use this rather than Laplace for all binomial analyses in this paper to be consistent? (None of the others have convergence problems, but I don’t want to appear to cherry-pick results in any way.)

Here's the code with each estimation:

**Laplace**:

```r
model_LLH2.1 <- glmer(cbind(Capital, nTrials-Capital) ~ 1 + 
    WordType*Grade + (1|ID), family=binomial(link="logit"), 
    data = LLH2w, 
    control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", 
                         optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)), 
                         na.action=na.omit)
```

**AG-HQ**:

```r
model_LLH2.1a <- glmer(cbind(Capital, nTrials-Capital) ~ 1 + 
    WordType*Grade + (1|ID), family=binomial(link="logit"), 
    data = LLH2w, 
    control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", 
                         optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)), na.action=na.omit, 
                         nAGQ = 0)
```

Predictors:

- Word type: key predictor, four levels
- Grade: four levels

Comment: Hi Emilia. Welcome to CV. I have trimmed down a bit and formatted the codes for better readability.

Comment: roughly speaking, Laplace can be seen as AGH with a single quadrature point. ON the other hand, from the ´glmer` help page: _A value of zero uses a faster but less exact form of parameter estimation for GLMMs by optimizing the random effects and the fixed-effects coefficients in the penalized iteratively reweighted least squares step. (See Details.)_ thus, be super careful when working with ´nAGQ=0`.